# IIS doesnt work with "location path code" on web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Error trying to access into a folder on IIS:

the first users has access to everything, while the other cant.

```
<authentication mode="Windows">

</authentication>
<authorization>
   <allow users="Domain\AnotherDomain"/>
   <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

This is the code im using to grant access to the users, because the IIS doesnt recognize the Active Directory "roles":

```
 <location path="~/UsuarioTI">
 <system.web>
    <authorization>
    <allow users ="Domain\MyDomain" />
    <deny users="*"/>
 </authorization>
</system.web>
```

this is the error when im trying to enter into the website,

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

Is there anything else that i need to install, besides enable windows authentication and disable the rest of them?

PD: whenever i try to access into the path im allowed to, it's asking for the user with 'AnotherDomain',because the other has no access.

PD2: How to recognize roles on IIS or throught localhost?

Comment: `system.web` is for ASP.NET, not IIS. Read IIS log files please, so as to know what exactly is the sub status for the 401 errors. You were on the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS check the Pool Application Name you used for your website and then 
add on the folder permissions as follow : IIS AppPool\poolName

poolName => is the name of you Pool Application !

That the virtual user created, you won't find it in the search, just add it as I mentioned above.